# Android: How to handle multiple account entry points

Tags: android

I'm sorry if this question is a little low-quality, kindly notify me about what to do if it is.

I just want to make a clarification. I am working on an app where users can sign up as three different types of users (student, parent or teacher). I want to know how this is usually done.

My current approach is to separate all of the Java/Kotlin files relating to each of the three user types into three different packages and simply follow the flow (from authentication). I feel that this is a little bogus and inefficient. How can I achieve this same feat with less files and less complexity?

If I'm supposed to include something I did not (snapshop, code snippet, etc), please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Keep going with that approach.  When you identify common code move it into a shared package.  Repeat.

Comment: I can barely imagine an alternative approach.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much.